# Issue with displaying 'Submit' button on browser using Flask and Jinja2

Tags: python-3.x, web, flask, jinja2

So I am getting to know Flask and Jinja2 by doing some simple exercises using Pycharm, but then I got stuck at this part and could not find a way through.

I got a login.html file which has the following codes:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
     <form>
          <input type="text" id="email">
          <input type="password" id="password">
          <input type="submit" id="submit-button">
     </form>
{% endblock %}
```

and when I run the codes, it display the following on the browser, which is understandable as I have not used render_template from Flask:

[image]

then I go to my app.py file which has the following codes:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_method():
    return render_template('login.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=4995)
```

when I run the codes, it displays the following on browser which I dont understand why the submit button doesnt get rendered:

[image]

here is my base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Fancy blog</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you mind providing your `base.html`?

Comment: i have added it to the question @GreyLi

Comment: I am not able to replicate this problem. Using the setup as described in the question, the submit button renders correctly.

Comment: do you think its something wrong with my browser settings? I tried disabling cache and all but nothing works... @MattHealy

Comment: The code you provided seems no problem.

Comment: thanks @GreyLi, would you mind recommending some solutions regarding my problems if its not coding problems?

Comment: Try to use another browser?